# How to skip any particular indexer from indexing when cron runs?

Tags: magento2, cron, indexing

I have configured cron (`php bin/magento cron:run`) which runs every minute. One of the tasks this cron job does is to update all indexers in Magento.

When the indexing is run via this cron job, I want to skip/exclude indexing for a particular indexer, let's say `catalog_category_product` from indexing and allow indexing for other indexers.

For this particular indexer, I will configure another cron (`php bin/magento indexer:reindex catalog_category_product`) which will run less frequent (not every minute).

So, how to exclude `catalog_category_product` from indexing when cron runs?

Comment: Change the mode of the specific indexer to Update on Save.

Comment: I want to run this indexer via update by schedule only(once or twice a day) but not when cron runs.